# Roots of linear combinations of trigonometric functions

Tags: trigonometry

How many roots does $a\cos x + b \sin x = 0$ have, if $x \in [0, \pi]$, and $a$ and $b$ are nonzero? I deduced that it has at most one, but I am quite aware of my carelessness in trigonometry, so could you check my proof?

Using the "[R-formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_trigonometric_identities#Linear_combinations)", we get $\sqrt{a^2 + b^2}\sin(x + \varphi) = 0$, where $\varphi \in [-\pi/2, \pi/2]$. Thus $x + \varphi$ is a multiple of $\pi$, but since $x + \varphi \in [-\pi/2, 3\pi/2]$ (by summing their ranges), either

- $x + \varphi = 0$, thus $x = -\varphi$, or
- $x + \varphi = \pi$, thus $x = \pi - \varphi$.

So $x$ can have at most one solution. Is this line of reasoning valid?

Comment: We don't need $\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$ if the RHS=0 as we have $\tan x=-\frac ab$ and the period of $\tan x$ is $\pi$

Comment: AH! I totally did not see that! Nice one! I feel silly now